# Heroku App crashes immediately with R10 and H10 errors

Tags: python, heroku, flask

My app runs fine locally using foreman run, and when I execute my `runserver.py` file using `python runserver.py`. When I push it to Heroku, it just crashes. I even made changes to my procfile: `web: python runserver.py ${PORT}` so that Heroku will bind to a port number, but to no avail...I've been at this problem for almost 3 days now. First with my `Procfile` and now with Heroku...any help would gladly be appreciated. Additionally, I am using Python with the Flask framework for this project -- I came across Heroku forward, but it seems to be only for RoR applications..

```
2014-02-24T02:24:50.146153+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
    2014-02-24T02:24:51.323561+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
    2014-02-24T02:24:51.333621+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2014-02-24T02:24:51.334368+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2014-02-24T02:24:55.793531+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python runserver.py`
    2014-02-24T02:24:57.117683+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    2014-02-24T02:24:57.117683+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Restarting with reloader
    2014-02-24T02:23:43.987388+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy c55f7b6 by shaunktw@gmail.com
    2014-02-24T02:23:43.987478+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by shaunktw@gmail.com
    2014-02-24T02:25:56.204701+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
    2014-02-24T02:25:56.204929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
    2014-02-24T02:25:57.495657+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

Procfile:

```
web: python runserver.py ${PORT}
```

runserver.py:

```
from intro_to_flask import app

app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: It looks like you've shared your `Procfile` instead of `runserver.py`.

Comment: @dirn okay my bad, just edited.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer to this issue...essentially I had to bind a port and specify the host that I am using:

In my runserver.py file I modified it using:

```
import os
from intro_to_flask import app

port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

It's probably not the most elegant way of doing it.but it works.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify `$PORT` instead of `${PORT}` like

```
web: python runserver.py $PORT
```

Comment: I made the change and my app is still crashing with the same error..not sure why it would take more than 60 secs to load.

Comment: On Heroku's website they [talk about using gunicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#declare-process-types-with-procfile). Is that an option for you? I don't know much Python.

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://virantha.com/2013/11/14/starting-a-simple-flask-app-with-heroku/) gives a simple example to start Flask app with Heroku