# How to tell Heroku Terminal to execute "flask run" command

Tags: python, pandas, flask, heroku

I want to deploy a Flask app on Heroku but I don't know how to tell Heroku terminal to execute "flask run" command

Comment: what does your Procfile look like?

Comment: web: gunicorn run:app

Comment: Then if your Flask app is named app and instantiated inside a file named run.py you should be fine.

Comment: Well that's not the case.
I made some changes in ProcFile : "web: python app.py"
This is the Log
2022-03-07T16:33:33.303463+00:00 app[web.1]: Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:30489/
2022-03-07T16:33:33.303712+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
2022-03-07T16:33:33.303771+00:00 app[web.1]:    WARNING: This is a development server
2022-03-07T16:33:33.303793+00:00 app[web.1]:    Use a production WSGI server instead.
2022-03-07T16:34:21.188052+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Comment: As others have said, you probably need to bind the right port, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22056973/3275464